# ASUS Armoury Crate installation fails with error 102

Tags: windows-10, asus, armoury-crate

I'm using the Armoury Crate installer version 3.1.3.0. Nearly at the end of the installation, the installation fails with the following error message:

> **Installation Failed**
>
> Installation Failed. Please restart the system and check the internet connection status before retrying.102

Restarting the system does not help and my internet connection is fine. I also used the Armoury Crate Uninstaller to delete the software and I additionally deleted all remaining traces of the software manually (services, program files, scheduled tasks, registry), but a fresh installation fails with the same error message.

How can I successfully install Armoury Crate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more in depth testing, it turned out:

You cannot install that software as an unprivileged user even if you elevate the installer with UAC. You have to logon as a privileged user and install the software then.

Unfortunately, the installer installs Armoury Crate as a Windows Store App and does this only for the user who performs the installation. If you log back in as your normal user you will not be able to launch Armory Crate.

All in all, not the best software engineering behind this piece of shoftware.